# Linux Installation Repackaging

Tags: linux, development-environment, ubuntu

I am looking for a way to build a development environment (IDE, Databases, etc...) within a fresh linux install, and then repackage that setup into an installation that can be installed on other machines (new developers).  Does anyone know of any tools to do this?  I am using Kubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm I have not read too much good stuff about the KDE in Ubuntu. Anyway, if (and that's a big IF) you would like to look into openSUSE instead, there is the SUSE studio: http://susestudio.com/ See this FAQ: http://susestudio.com/help/faq.html

Comment: I am actually in the process of looking at that, but I cannot figure out how to preconfigure phpstorm within it?

Comment: Hmm if this is not part of openSUSE, you can do this: http://susestudio.com/help/faq.html#how_can_i_upload_custom_rpms Besides, you can upload & change files within the appliance - so you can bring in your configuration.

Comment: This actually works REALLY well.  You can create it, set up the dev environment using a disk image and testrunner, export the changed files and push them back into the build and rebuild it as an ISO.  GREAT!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to build your own `.deb` package. In that package you can add all your dependencies and programs you need. I think that would be the cleanest solution with some benefits like versions etc.

We use that in combination with [FAI](http://fai-project.org/) in our company.

**Update:**

Are you familiar with `.deb` packages?  We generally use the packages that ship with Ubuntu if possible.

Anyway, assume you have some software that is not in the Ubuntu repo, for example Eclipse with some pre-installed plugins and other fancy stuff. I will give you an idea with a simplified step by step instruction.

- Download Eclipse
- Unpack the eclipse archive to `/tmp/eclipse`
- Configure eclipse and install some plugins

At this point your eclipse installation is ready to use. So now let's create a `.deb` file containing that eclipse installation. There are many tutorials howto create a debian package, i will show you a simple way.

- Somewhere create a folder where you will package your stuff. I will use `/home/user/packages/eclipse`
- in that folder create a folder `DEBIAN`
- copy your eclipse installation from `/tmp/eclipse/` to `/home/user/packages/eclipse/opt/development/eclipse`
- in the DEBIAN folder create three files: `control`, `postinst` and `postrm`

Put something like the following into the control file:

```
Package: eclipse
Version: 1.0
Architecture: all
Maintainer: Your Name <somethat@somewhere.com>
Depends: openjdk-7-jdk
Section: development
Priority: optional
Description: Eclipse with some plugins
```

In the `postinst` you create a symlink from your eclipse executable to say `/usr/local/bin/eclipse`.

In the `postrm` you remove that symlink.

By now you should have a directory structure like the following:

```
eclipse
├── DEBIAN
│   ├── control
│   ├── postinst
│   └── postrm
└── opt
    └── development
        └── eclipse
            ├── about_files
            ├── about.html
            ├── artifacts.xml
            ├── configuration
            ├── dropins
            ├── eclipse
            ├── eclipse.ini
            ├── epl-v10.html
            ├── features
            ├── icon.xpm
            ├── libcairo-swt.so
            ├── notice.html
            ├── p2
            ├── plugins
            └── readme
```

Change into `/home/user/packages` and execute `dpkg-deb --build eclipse .` You should now have your eclipse debian package (`eclipse_1.0_all.deb`) that is ready to install on the other computers.

The next step would be to setup a APT repository :)

Copy the package to the new comupter and run `dpkg -i <packagename>` to install the package.

Hope i could help.

[HOWTO build debian binary packages](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Debian-Binary-Package-Building-HOWTO/)

Comment: How would I go about building deb packages?  What I need is a grouping of third party software along with our own database snapshot and git snapshot.  Git/database are easy.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [preseeding](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/preseed-using.html).
It's a technique that allows you to pre-define installation flow.

Comment: This looks great, but I am wondering if there is a way to do this with an actual image?  Ideally, we should do it with preseeding, but the stakeholder obviously has that call and I think he might bite on it harder if it was on a disk and he didn't have to trust server hardware to deliver it.

Comment: Preseeding can install anything from a disk as well. If repository on a disk will contain all the needed packages - you just specify disk as an installation source without relying on the internet. Installation of custom software can then be either deb packages or just scripted post-install routines or whatever you need, basically.